# Google Chrome - Remove Focus Border and Page Jumping

Tags: css, google-chrome

this is my first post on StackOverflow so please bear with me if I'm not understanding things properly.

There are pages on Google Chrome that have boxes for text input, which get highlighted in blue as a focus border. I'm scrolled down on a page below the text box and start typing, the page jumps back up to where the text input is so I can't read the contents below it. This doesn't happen on Firefox.

My question is different because it's not the highlighted focus that I have a problem with, it's that the page keeps jumping up to where the text input is. I've used various CSS code to get rid of the focus border but it still doesn't stop the page from jumping.

```
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

and

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

and

```
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
}
```

Is there any way to write CSS to stop the page from scrolling to the text input area when I don't want it to?

Comment: Need HTML, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Don't ever remove the focus highlight. Its there for a very good reason, and you are sacrificing usability for purely aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is using JavaScript on this one.
You can use:

```
<body onLoad="window.scroll(x, y)">
```

Where x and y will be numbers where you want your starting scrolling position will be.